# Extracting a List<Page> from a List<Book> with a lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying to extract a List of Page from a List of type Book, where the page id matches the supplied value.

A Book contains a List of Pages. Each Page has an Id.

I just can't seem to get it right. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
List<Book> books = GetBooks();
Page page = books.Select(x => x.Pages.Where(y => y.PageId == pageId)).Single();
```

Comment: You want it to return `IEnumerable<Page>` ? Can you have multiple pages with the same Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Book> books = GetBooks();
IEnumerable<Page> pages = books.SelectMany(x => x.Pages.Where(y => y.PageId == pageId));
```

This should give you a Enumeration of the pages with the given id. You need to add `.ToList()` if you want a list instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2). This is for if there can be multiple pages in a book with the given `pageId`:

```
var pages = books.SelectMany(book => book.Pages.Where(page => page.PageId == pageId));
```

However, if there can be only a single page in a book with the given `pageId`, you might want:

```
var pages = books.Select(book => book.Pages.Single(page => page.PageId == pageId));
```

If there may or may not be a page in a book with the given `pageId`, then you probably want this:

```
var pages = hooks.SelectMany(book => book.Pages).Where(x => x.PageId == pageId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `SelectMany`:

```
Page page = books.SelectMany(x => x.Pages).Where(x => x.PageId == pageId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

And the LINQ version of that query is:

```
from b in books
from p in b.Pages
where p.PageId == pageId
select p
```

Which is nice because you get the `SelectMany` behavior by drilling-down with`from` clauses.